# Understanding the Editorial for Prime XOR - HackerRank

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, boolean-logic, xor

*Disclaimer: This question involves content from the corresponding editorial. Thus, if you want to attempt this problem on your own, I discourage you from reading this post. Also, my question leaves out some details mentioned in the editorial, so please do refer to the editorial as you read my question.*

*Also, please bear in my mind that it is not my intention to advertise for HackerRank; furthermore, in no way, am I taking credit for the content on the editorial, problem description, or any other material that would be deemed a copyright infringement by HackerRank or affiliated parties).*

---

**Actual Question**:

I'm trying to understand the editorial for this [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/prime-xor). Specifically, the part that I'm getting confused over is the following piece of code:

```
...
for(int i=1;i<=k;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<8192;j++) {
        mem[flag][j] = (mem[flag^1][j]*(1+(a[v[i-1]])/2))%mod + (mem[flag^1][j^v[i-1]]*((a[v[i-1]]+1)/2))%mod;
        if(mem[flag][j]>=mod)
            mem[flag][j]%=mod;
    }
    flag = flag^1;
}
```

The editorial states that "...Using this property, we can write a `O(N)` dynammic programming solution with `8192` constant factor such that `dp[i][j]` would store the count of subsets that can be formed with the first  elements such that the xor-sum of the elements in the subset is `j`."

From the code, it appears that `mem` is essentially `dp`, except I can't wrap my head around the function of `flag` -- what *is* `flag`?. Also, I get that `1 + (a[v[i - 1]])/2` corresponds with the number of evens in [0, a[v[i - 1]]] and `(a[v[i - 1]] + 1) / 2`corresponds with the number of odds in that same interval, but I don't see how it quite ties in with everything.

Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Explanation of Flag

This is a standard approach to reduce memory usage when using dynamic programming.

The idea is that often each row of a DP array only depends on the previous row.  In this case, instead of storing the whole 2d DP[i][j] array, you can instead just use 2 rows of the array.

In other words, DP[i][j] is stored in mem[0][j] if i is even, and in mem[1][j] if i is odd.  The mem array is reused multiple times and after each iteration holds the most recent two rows of the full DP array.

### Explanation of recurrence

Suppose we have 5 duplicates of a certain value v.  There are 1+5/2 ways of making an xor of 0 (take either 0,2 or 4 copies).  There are (1+5)/2 ways of making an xor of v (take either 1,3 or 5 copies).

So to make the new value j, we can either start with j and add 0,2 or 4 copies of v, or start with j^v and add 1,3 or 5 copies.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: As I tried this problem for 2 days to get it accepted using hash-table instead of normal array which should be faster(because all the xor-s concentrate to small number of values). For odd-even technique, I used `dp[i&1][xorval]` and `dp[(i+1)&1][xorval]`, which is my favorite technique.

Answer (score 0):

flag is used to reduce excess use of memory since dp is dependent upon previous state only .

why loop [0,8192] : As it is given in the question that a[i]<=4500 then when we xor two number it will reach upto 8192 . 
Xor property ..